# Bind values from database to dropdown in MVC with Entity frame work

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-3

I am trying to bind a value from database to the dropdown in View.

I have a requirement that I need to display database values in dropdown list in a view.  I am trying to bind the Email id to the dropdown from the database table.

Here I need to add the Email ID to the dropdown. This is my Model,

```
public class UserDetails
{
      public List<SelectListItem> Userdetails { get; set; }
      public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

This is My Controller,

```
public ActionResult Admin()
{
            var db = new DataEntities1();
            var query = db.tblEmployees.Select(c => new { c.Email });
            ViewBag.Categories = new SelectList(query.AsEnumerable(), "CategoryID", "CategoryName");
            return View();
}
```

This is my View,

```
   @model List<MVC_Sample.Models.UserDetails>

             <div class="dropdown">
               @Html.DropDownList("CategoryID", (SelectList)ViewBag.Categories, "--Select One--")

                </div>
```

View will be loaded with dropdown and the values from database. But unfortunately, I am not able to add the values to drop down. I dono where I did the wrong here. Can anyone help me on this..

Comment: what is CategoryID and CategoryName ??

Comment: Are you sure `CategoryID` & `CategoryName` instead of `Email` as text & value field passed as `SelectList` to view? Probably you want to use `ViewBag.Categories = new SelectList(query.AsEnumerable(), "Email", "Email");`.

Comment: Your not even returning your model to the view, and your `@model List<UserDetails>` makes no sense at all. Are you wanting to create multiple dropdowns (one for each `UserDetails`)? And you query makes no sense - its returning just one property and does not contain a properties `CategoryID` and `CategoryName`. What are you trying to do here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As other users coment you on the comments, the problems may be, that `CategoryID` and `CategoryName` are not present on thq `query`

However, I usually prefer to bind the dropdown to `List<SelectListItem>` instead of bind it to a `SelectList`, because it make easier to create a strong typed query.

I would change these lines on the controller:

```
var query = db.tblEmployees.Select(c => new { c.Email });
ViewBag.Categories = new SelectList(query.AsEnumerable(), "CategoryID", "CategoryName");
```

To:

```
List<SelectListItem> query = db.tblEmployees.Select(c => new SelectListItem { Text = c.Email, Value = c.CategoryId }).toList();
ViewBag.Categories = query;
```

Then, in the view. you should change

```
@Html.DropDownList("CategoryID", (SelectList)ViewBag.Categories, "--Select One--")
```

To:

```
@Html.DropDownList("CategoryID", (List<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.Categories, "--Select One--")
```

Comment: OP has a property `List<SelectListItem> Userdetails` so that is what should be assigned, not `ViewBag` - and in the view `@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.CategoryID, Model.Userdetails, "...")`